# Is it possible to automatically close a port in use after I stop running the script?

Tags: python, linux, macos, terminal

I'm running python scripts in the terminal which use the :5000 port.

Each time I stop the script, make changes then re-run, I get a errno:48 port in use. I then have to manually find the port in use and then kill the PID before I can run the script again:

```
dpadmins-MacBook:microblog presentation$ ps -fa
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0   326   324   0  8:48am ttys000    0:00.03 login -pf presentation
  502   330   326   0  8:48am ttys000    0:00.10 -bash
  502   854   330   0  9:37am ttys000    0:00.05 python
  502   885   330   0  9:53am ttys000    0:00.21 flask/bin/python ./run.py
  502   886   885   0  9:53am ttys000    0:01.22 /Users/presentation/Documents/webprojects/mainflask/microblog/flask/bin/python ./run.py
    0   930   330   0 10:08am ttys000    0:00.01 ps -fa

dpadmins-MacBook:microblog presentation$ kill -9 885
```

Is there a way around this so I don't have to run this procedure every time?

Comment: You could consider registering an [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) function to close the port when your program terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script does not terminate as it should. Why not writing a PID file to be able to limit instances and then bail out with an error that your script is already running with PID  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of kill and netstat command to kill process which are running with port 5000

```
kill -9 `netstat -lnp|grep :5000|awk '{ print $7}'|awk -F/ '{ print $1 }'`
```